# Is there a way to auto-adjust editor group sizes in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a small laptop screen and when I code in HTML, CSS and JS in three separate editor groups in VS Code, it becomes a tedious task to switch between 3 editor groups because I have to adjust their sizes again and again to make space [like this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ly48cs6JSRwsEWPZf2D-52dwz5UuWECR/view?usp=share_link). It's a bit exaggerated example but I really do struggle with that. Is there an extension or something that automatically adjust editor group sizes when I click on them or anything similar that can solve this problem?

Please note that:

1. VS Code has a similar feature like this but it only works when editor group sizes are too small but I just want the editor groups to adjust a little bit so that I can both code in one editor group and see the other groups a bit too.
2. Also, I can not decrease the font size as my laptop screen is already small (in case if u think that might be a solution)

Comment: Have you considered stacking two of the tabs on top of each other?

Comment: wjandrea, Yes but that workflow doesn't suit me.. I want to work in vertical tabs

Comment: what about, ahem, bigger external monitor?

Comment: open a version of all files in all tab groups, edit in the largest tab group and select a view of another file in the smaller tab group.

Comment: strictly speaking, these are called "editor groups" and not "tabs". Using the right terminology is important here. the word "tab" is already a bit overloaded in the VS Code terminology.

Comment: If the problem is that you don't want horizontal overflow (and associated horizontal scrollbar) to happen, why not just turn on word wrapping? (`View: Toggle Word Wrap` command in command palette)?